# Would this question have been welcomed?

Tags: discussion, scope

So I was keen to post this [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91482/neo-liberalism-language-and-freedom) here but was worried it would be considered too broad or something else (the ideas are agued from a linguistics perspective as well)? Would it have been welcomed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, [crossposting on Stack Exchange is generally discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Posting the same question on more than one SE site leads to redundant answers on multiple sites. For that reason every question should only be posted on one SE site - the one where you believe that it will receive the best answers.

But as an academic exercise, let's take a look at this question in particular, and see how well it would fit on Politics Stack Exchange if it had **not** been posted on another SE site already.

First of all, it's really a philosophical question. With all the quotes from philosophers, it really seems right at home on Philosophy Stack Exchange. But behind all those quotations, what the question is actually asking is about how to define the word "freedom". And - as the question already demonstrates - there does not appear to be an expert consensus on the topic. That makes this a question which falls into the "primarily opinion-based" territory.

And in general we really do not like opinon-based questions on Politics Stack Exchange, because with how emotionally laden politics are, they often end up in angry flamewars.

Comment: Cheers .. I think I should spend time browsing some questions:)